Get body nodes from x-www-form-urlencoded in slack app
i have an slack app built in typescript, i'm trying to call a webhook trigger from a slash command the problem that i'm facing is that when i try to get a node from the body it is mapped as an empty string "", anyone has faced the same?
const trigger: Trigger<typeof PrSendManuallyWorkflow.definition> = {
    type: TriggerTypes.Webhook,
    name: "Trigger when a new PR is received by slash command",
    workflow: `#/workflows/${PrSendManuallyWorkflow.definition.callback_id}`,
    inputs: {
        channel_id: {
            value: "{{data.channel_id}}"
        },
    },
};


not sure if helpful, but this rings a bell when I was building an alert server got tripped up for a while on that the message body key was named "text", but you can test whats being output by cURL-ing the trigger

Thanks, but it’s not exactly what I was looking for, I can’t debug an app like this because it’s deployed in slack, and also I can’t add logs at app trigger level because the framework doesn’t allow me to do that

whip it up as a webhook so you can play around with the payloads in postman or with curl, https://api.slack.com/automation/triggers/webhook
